# Object Serialization error

Tags: php, cookies

I am getting this error when I serialize an object in PHP and write the contents to a cookie an then read the contents of the same cookie on another page and unserialize it:

Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 43 of 1633 bytes in.....

I know this may have been answered elsewhere but those solutions are not working out since the mention of cookies is not there.

ClassA.php

```
Class A {
 private $mem1;
 private $mem2;

 __construct($m1,$m2) {
 $this->mem1 = m1;
 $this->mem2 = m2;
 }

 function serializeAndWriteToCookie() {
  $serializedString = serialize($this);
  $result = setcookie("serializedObjectCookie", $serializedString, time() + 3600, "/");
 }
}//end class definition
```

page1.php

```
require_once 'ClassA.php';

    $objA = new A(1,2);
    $objA->serializeAndWriteToCookie();
```

page2.php

```
require_once 'ClassA.php';

$serializedObjectContent = $_COOKIE['serializedObjectCookie'];
$objContent = unserialize($serializedObjectContent);
```

AND NOW I GET THAT ERROR MESSAGE ABOVE.....any suggestions?

Comment: Look at the value you're trying to unserialize... what's at offset 43? But in general you should [**avoid unserializing user input**, even the manual warns against doing it](http://php.net/unserialize#refsect1-function.unserialize-notes).

Comment: May be the problem with __sleep() method? when serialize used for object, this object "sleeps", and you use it code in this object. Try to serialize($objA) in page1.php and look what happens.

Comment: There are a few syntax errors in your `class A` definition. Should we assume those are copy-paste errors, and not actual errors? - Posting actual code, rather than broken imitations of it, helps. Saves time.